# Change the session remote user in AngularJS file and redirect to main page in ColdFusion file

Tags: angularjs, coldfusion

I have the `main.cfc` file where I am setting the view based on the user that is logged in. I have admin view and I have user view.

Admin view is decided based on the ids i add to the list. 
I want to give option for admin to change to see view like a specific user.

I have `ng-click="switchView"`

This calls a function in the AngularJS

```
$scope.switchView = function(){

    // I want to cfset session.remoteuser = userid
    // and redirect to main page to change the view

}
```

Is this possible? How can i achieve it?

Comment: Is `session.remoteUser` known when the page is generated? Does it change as the page is used?

Comment: You have to decide what to do about the fact that session.remoteuser is a variable that runs on the server, and js code runs on the client.

Comment: is there a way i can set the session.remoteuser in the .cfm file and call the main page ?

Comment: Just as a general practice I prefer to pass my CF variables on the CFM page as hidden inputs or data attributes that can then be accessed by my JS script.

Comment: can you give code example please?

Comment: On CFM page:  <input type="hidden" id="myid" value="<cfoutput>#myValue#</cfoutput>"/>
Then using your preferred JavaScript DOM access method (I prefer jQuery but Angular has DOM access as well):  <script>var myIdValue = $("#myid").val();</script>

Comment: @JasonHolden You should write this up as an answer

Comment: @JamesAMohler I'm not sure that is the appropriate answer to this question.  Just more of a good way to get CF variable information INTO JavaScript.  It still seems like there will still be a server-side call necessary if the original poster wants to SET the variable FROM JavaScript.